# Why does rainbow() gives me an # followed by 8 digits rather 6?

Tags: r, colors

I tried the function rainbow(3) in R to give me some rainbow colours. However the string that got output was

```
"#FF0000FF" "#00FF00FF" "#0000FFFF"
```

I was only expect 6 digits after #. How come it's giving 8 digits? Does it have to do with me using a 64 bit machine? How do I convert the above to 6 digits only?

Comment: Look at the output of `rainbow(3,alpha=0)` and guess what the last two digits denote.

Comment: how noob of me. please answer or i will answer and get the points myself.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will get a better R color education by looking at:

```
?rgb
?col2rgb
demo('colors')
```